# Can not compile php-curl ext with custom curl

Tags: linux, php, curl, compilation, php8.1

I have libcurl installed here:

/usr/local/curl-7.88.1/

I want to compile php-curl extension:

```
# cd /usr/src/php-8.1.12/ext/curl/

# /usr/local/php81/bin/phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20210902
Zend Module Api No:      20210902
Zend Extension Api No:   420210902

# ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php81/bin/php-config --with-curl=/usr/local/curl-7.88.1/
...
checking for cURL support... yes, shared
checking for libcurl >= 7.29.0... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libcurl >= 7.29.0) were not met:

No package 'libcurl' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CURL_CFLAGS
and CURL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I tried several workarounds, including setting CFLAGS and LDFLAGS, but result is the same.

If I install `yum install libcurl-devel`, it ignores `--with-curl=/usr/local/curl-7.88.1/` and works with the system `libcurl` (old version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was made possible to compile using following flags

```
export CFLAGS="-std=c99"
export MYCDIR=/usr/local/curl-7.88.1
export CURL_CFLAGS=-I$MYCDIR/include
export CURL_LIBS="-L$MYCDIR/lib -lcurl"
```